# Using noscript to modify html element and redirect page when JS is disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, css, noscript

I currently have a page that uses a modified version of jQuery UI accordion. Link for reference for jQuery UI accordion: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>abc</p>
  </div>

  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>def</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For my page, if I am hitting url:

> www.whatever.com/getWater

I will be reaching the page that "Section 1" is active.

If I am hitting url:

> www.whatever.com/getFood

I will be reaching the page that "Section 2" is active.

This page would not function with JS disabled and I need to make sure the page at least still have the basic function when JS is disabled.

So the issue:

Assuming when I am at `/getWater` with JS disabled, "Section 1" is active and content shows up, I will not able to click "Section 2" to expand the content of section 2 without JS.

So currently I am thinking one possible solution for this is to use `<noscript>` to change the `<h3>` tag into a link, i.e `<a>` tag,  when we detect the page is JS disabled

So it becomes to this(or whatever it should be, I am a noob on this):

```
<div id="accordion">
  <a>Section 1</a>
  <div>
    <p>abc</p>
  </div>

  <a>Section 2</a>
  <div>
    <p>def</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in `<noscript>`, i add the link that can lead me to `/getFood` so "Section 2" will be displayed, and vise versa.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

How about if you do something like this?

Add css in `<noscript>` which display `a` and hide `h3`, check code below:

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <a>Section 1 </a> 
  <div>
    <p>abc</p>
  </div>

  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <a>Section 2</a> 
  <div>
    <p>def</p>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
 a{display:none;}
</style>


<noscript>
 <style>
 a{display:block !important} 
 h3 {display:none}
 </style> 
</noscript>
```